# (R) Mutate column conditionally (equal to or nearest greater)

Tags: r, dplyr

Sup,

Consider the following data frames:

## DATA

```
df1=data.frame(
  column1=c('a','b','c','d','e'),
  column2=c('PF', 'PF', 'PJ', 'PF', 'PJ'),
  column3=c(0.965, 0.92, 0.98, 0.99, 0.88)
  )

df2=data.frame(
  column1=c(1,0.983,0.97,0.957,0.92, 1,0.982,0.96,0.94,0.89),
  column2=c('PF', 'PF', 'PF', 'PF', 'PF', 'PJ', 'PJ', 'PJ', 'PJ', 'PJ'),
  column3=c(4,3,2,1,1,4,3,2,1,1)
)
```

#### df1

```
  column1 column2 column3
1       a      PF   0.965
2       b      PF   0.920
3       c      PJ   0.980
4       d      PF   0.990
5       e      PJ   0.880
```

#### df2

```
   column1 column2 column3
1    1.000      PF       4
2    0.983      PF       3
3    0.970      PF       2
4    0.957      PF       1
5    0.920      PF       1
6    1.000      PJ       4
7    0.982      PJ       3
8    0.960      PJ       2
9    0.940      PJ       1
10   0.890      PJ       1
```

I need a `column4` on `df1` that returns`df2` `column3`. Conditions are:

1. both `column2` match;
2. `df2` `column1` should be equal to or nearest greater than `df1` `column3`.

So expected result would be:

```
  column1 column2 column3 column4
1       a      PF   0.965       2
2       b      PF   0.920       1
3       c      PJ   0.980       3
4       d      PF   0.990       4
5       e      PJ   0.880       1
```

Any ideas (especially `dplyr` solutions)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
library(dplyr)

df1=data.frame(
  column1=c('a','b','c','d','e'),
  column2=c('PF', 'PF', 'PJ', 'PF', 'PJ'),
  column3=c(0.965, 0.92, 0.98, 0.99, 0.88)
)

df2=data.frame(
  column1=c(1,0.983,0.97,0.957,0.92, 1,0.982,0.96,0.94,0.89),
  column2=c('PF', 'PF', 'PF', 'PF', 'PF', 'PJ', 'PJ', 'PJ', 'PJ', 'PJ'),
  column3=c(4,3,2,1,1,4,3,2,1,1)
)

result <-
  df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = "column2") %>% #Joining two tables together
  mutate(diff = column1.y - column3.x,
         diff = ifelse(diff < 0, NA, diff)) %>% # Calculating the difference
  group_by(column1.x, column2) %>%
  mutate(smallest_value = min(diff, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% # Getting min difference each group
  filter(diff == smallest_value) %>% # Selecting only relevant values
  select(column1.x, column2, column3.x, column3.y) %>% # For presentation purpose
  rename(column1 = column1.x,
         column3 = column3.x,
         column4 = column3.y)
```

In this code what I am trying to do is to calculate the difference between the respective columns and then choosing that of the minimum difference that is not negative (hence nearest one to it), then I select this column and display it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

x <- df1 %>% 
  fuzzy_inner_join(df2,by = c("column2" = "column2","column3" = "column1"),match_fun = c(`==`,`<=`))

x %>% 
  group_by(column1.x) %>% 
  filter(column1.y == max(column1.y)) %>% 
  select(column1.x,column2.x,column3.x,column1.y)

# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   column1.x [5]
  column1.x column2.x column3.x column1.y
  <fct>     <fct>         <dbl>     <dbl>
1 a         PF            0.965         1
2 b         PF            0.92          1
3 c         PJ            0.98          1
4 d         PF            0.99          1
5 e         PJ            0.88          1
```

Comment: Maybe I missread and you need to change it to ,match_fun = c(`==`,`>=`)

Comment: Shouldn't return 1 in very row.